# RecyclerView items not populating (AndroidStudio, Room, MVVM)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one extra tragedy on top of the two epic battles awaiting us this weekend. I'm trying to create a fitness-tracking app for my portfolio.

Within the app, all seems well - AndroidStudios's emulator is clearly displaying the RecyclerView element (I set the dark background and weird margins to be clearly visibly). And the database appears to be populating correctly. But no items will appear to populate the RecyclerView. At this point, I'm just trying to get them to read "hello," but they will eventually need to store client data. (It's possible that I may have confused myself when attempting to switch from the latter case to the former in an effort to simplify the problem...)

AdminListActivity

```
public class AdminListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int NEW_USER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ViewModel mViewModel;
    private List<User> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_admin_list);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.admin_recycler_view);
        final UserListAdapter adapter = new UserListAdapter(this, mUsers);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // Get ViewModel from ViewModelProvider
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class);

        // Observer on LiveData returned by getAllUsers.
        mViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<User> users) {
                // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                adapter.setUsers(users);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == NEW_USER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            User user = new User(data.getStringExtra(RegisterFragment.EXTRA_REPLY));
            mViewModel.addUser(user);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "not saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

AdminListFragment

```
public class AdminListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView mUserRecyclerView;
    private Button mAddNewClient;

    public AdminListFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // required onClick method
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_list, container, false);

        mUserRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.admin_recycler_view);
        mUserRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mAddNewClient = view.findViewById(R.id.add_new_client);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_admin_list, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_new_client:              SingleFragmentActivity.fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new RegisterFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                // TODO: OR: add from contacts
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

UserListAdapter

```
public class UserListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserListAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    private List<User> mUsers = Collections.emptyList(); // Cached copy of users

    public UserListAdapter(Context context, List<User> mUsers) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        mUsers = users;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView userListItem;

        public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userListItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userListItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclyerview_user_list_item, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User current = mUsers.get(position);
        holder.userListItem.setText(current.getClientName());
    }

    // getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
    // mUsers has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();

    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private UserDao mUserDao;
    public Repository mRepository;
    public LiveData<List<User>> mAllUsers;

    public ViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new Repository(application);
        mAllUsers = mRepository.getAllUsers();
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers() { return mAllUsers; }

    public void addUser(User user) { mRepository.addUser(user); }

}
```

Repository

```
public class Repository {

    private UserDao mUserDao;
    private LiveData<List<User>> mAllUsers;

    public Repository(Application application) {
        UserDatabase db = UserDatabase.buildDatabase(application);
        mUserDao = db.userDao();
        mAllUsers = mUserDao.getAllUsers();
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
        return mAllUsers;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mUserDao).execute(user);
    }

    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

        private UserDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertAsyncTask(UserDao dao) {
            mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final User... params) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.addUser(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

XML for the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userListItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:text="HELLO"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML for recyclerview in the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="admin.AdminListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/admin_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclyerview_user_list_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

UserDatabase

```
@Database(entities = {User.class, Admin.class}, version = 6, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class UserDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static volatile UserDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
    public static final String SP_NAME = "users";

    public static UserDatabase buildDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (UserDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), UserDatabase.class, "users").build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * Override the onOpen method to populate the database.
     * For this sample, we clear the database every time it is created or opened.
     *
     * If you want to populate the database only when the database is created for the 1st time,
     * override RoomDatabase.Callback()#onCreate
     */
    private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            // If you want to keep the data through app restarts,
            // comment out the following line.
            new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Populate the database in the background.
     * If you want to start with more words, just add them.
     */
    private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final UserDao mDao;

        PopulateDbAsync(UserDatabase db) {
            mDao = db.userDao();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            // Start the app with a clean database every time.
            // Not needed if you only populate on creation.
            //mDao.deleteAll();

            User user = new User("Dickon", "d");
            mDao.addUser(user);
            user = new User("Pumpy", "d");
            mDao.addUser(user);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

UserDao

```
package database;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import User.User;
import admin.Admin;

@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert
    void addUser(User user);

    @Insert
    void createAdmin(Admin admin);

    @Query("select * from users")
    LiveData<List<User>> getUser();

    @Query
    ("SELECT * from users ORDER BY clientName")
    LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers();

    @Query("select * FROM users WHERE id = :id")
    List<User> getUserById(int id);

    @Query("select * FROM users WHERE clientName = :clientName LIMIT 1")
    List<User> getUserByName(String clientName);

    @Delete
    void DeleteUser(User user);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a users list in your view model observer before passing it to recyclerview adapter

Comment: Share your database and DAO.

Comment: Thanks Taseer, edited my original post to include them. p.mathew13, let me check on that.

Comment: Where is your `AdminListFragment` used?

Comment: Ferran, thanks for replying. AdminListFragment is called from LoginFragment. That much, at least, seems to be working - the RecyclerView displays correctly, albeit without any items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AdminListActivity you have

```
   setContentView(R.layout.fragment_admin_list);

   RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.admin_recycler_view);
   final UserListAdapter adapter = new UserListAdapter(this, mUsers);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

In your AdminListFragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_list, container, false);

    mUserRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.admin_recycler_view);
    mUserRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    ...
}
```

The `recyclerView` from your fragment is not the same as your `recyclerView` from your Activity. So, you can see users in your Activity but not in your fragment.
Your fragment `recyclerView` has no adapter.